# Git - cambiar de equipo sin perder los cambios locales

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Bueno actualmente estoy trabajando en mi rama **local**, y un rama **test** que lleva todos los cambios para después mezclarlos con la rama de producción **master**.

Mi duda es que **tengo mis cambios aún en local y aún no termino algunas cosas**, y recién compre un equipo nuevo porque el actual es algo lento,

El punto es que **quiero pasar mis cambios al equipo nuevo**, pero como aún no termino mis cambios en local, es conveniente hacer commit en mi rama test, o se puede hacer un rama solo para guardar estos cambios y afectar test y después hacer pull en el nuevo equipo.

**Como puedo pasar mis cambios locales de una lap a un equipo nuevo?**

Comment: Lo más sencillo es copiar la carpeta principal o "root " de un equipo a otro.

Comment: clone el repositorio en la nube, con eso ya tiene configurado el Git en el computador nuevo y copie los cambios nuevos cambio en su carpeta, la segunda opción es crear una nueva rama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos caminos a tomar:

**Solución 1:**

Sube tus cambios a una rama y luego los bajas en la otra compu

- git checkout -b 'temp'
- git commit -m 'mis cambios'
- git push origin temp

**Solución 2(lo más fácil):**

- Copia y pega tu proyecto, la carpeta `.git` que está dentro del proyecto contiene toda la info necesaria de los repos, tus branch locales, branch's remotos, tus stash, los commits remotos, tus commits locales, etc.

> **Tip adicional**: Comprime la carpeta antes de pasarla, es más rápido pasar un archivo que una carpeta con muchos archivos pequeños.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la 2da opción fue más sencilla de hacer, solo conectar a git con las credenciales y continuar trabajando, excelente muchas gracias!